# 'twittero' or 'twitteratore' when one is great a user on Twitter

Tags: grammar

Just saw a tweet saying,

> un dialogo tra due delle *twittere* più divertenti che conosco

Is *twittere* or *twittero* a word being normally used? It sounds right due to assonance with *quacchere* or *quacchero*, but what do you think of?

Comment: I think that all these questions about absurd borrowed words from the English language are pointless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is

> un dialogo tra le due twitter più divertenti che conosco

Comment: I disagree. "Twitter" in Italian cannot be assigned to a person, only to the site or the program. If you want a standard Italian derivation, use "twittatrici".

Comment: @mau …which is what [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/neologismi/searchNeologismi.jsp?abcd=abdc&pathFile=/sites/default/BancaDati/Osservatorio_della_Lingua_Italiana/Maggio_2012/twittatore.xml&lettera=T) suggests after all. Or, at least, they report it as "neologism".

Answer (score 4):

It is not :) 
We use "utente di twitter" (sing. - en. twitter user) and in that case we would use "un dialogo tra due delle utenti di twitter più divertenti che conosco" or "un dialogo tra due delle utenti di twitter più divertenti che io conosca"

Answer (score 2):

Simply "[twittatore/twittatrice](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/neologismi/searchNeologismi.jsp?abcd=abdc&pathFile=/sites/default/BancaDati/Osservatorio_della_Lingua_Italiana/Maggio_2012/twittatore.xml&lettera=T)" for "utente di Twitter". So "bravo/a twittatore/twittatrice" for "bravo/a utente di Twitter".

Answer (score 0):

As the other users suggested,  the English "twitter" or (less) "twittatore" are used. "Twittere" was probably made up by the user, playing with the assonance with "chiacchiere" (chitchat), somehow recalling two old women talking about gossip.